# Using stateful vs stateless handler classes in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, stateless, stateful

I got stuck in a situation where I have two options to implement a part of a project.

I have a handler interface which internally contains a couple of methods to handle the incoming requests. The interface has been implemented by multiple concrete classes.

**Option 1**

I have a domain object that I can pass it to constructor by defining the related handler object with new keyword. So, it would be a stateful class, where I can not get benefit from having bean. In other words, I can not annotate the class with bean annotations such @component or @service.

**Option 2**

I can define handler classes as spring bean. But, in this case I will have to pass the domain object to each method (stateless) that is defined in the interface. It is a bit weird.

Can you tell me what is the disadvantage of option 1 in terms of memory? You know for each request I will need to create a new object in option 1, whereas I will use the bean which will be handled by spring ioc in the option 2.

The both solution works as I implemented and tried. But, I want to know pros/cons.

Comment: For option 1 the object will be deconstructed(erased) once it becomes out of scope. Whereas using option 2 would be more efficient on memory because the reference of the domain object will be passed to all the methods.

Comment: How do you define `efficiency` here?

Comment: @Utkarsh can you clarify that point?

Comment: As you mentioned, when we are using bean it will create the object once in the container, and when you are passing the domain object it will pass as reference to each method.